# Is it possible for an element to only listen to click events and ignore events like mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is the following: I have a div, which has some crucial mouse events I need to fetch. These are onMouseOver to be more precise.

However, when the mouse hover over this div, I am creating a few buttons on this div, which are then leading to misbehavious of my onMouseOver event, as they are overlaying the div, and as soon as the mouse is being moved onto those buttons, it "leaves" the div and the event stops triggering.

So, I want to be able to ignore mouse movement on these buttons, but I still want to grab the click event when someone clicks the buttons, of course.

The closest I've found so far was

```
pointer-event: none
```

, but that also disables click events.

Is there something else I could use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events if using jQuery.  `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions do not bubble from child to parent, so you end up triggering a `mouseout` event when you hover the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can always attach onmouseover event to these buttons and put in the same function as for div.

Even if You ignores onmouseover on this buttons You will lost onmouseover on the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventdefault(). after that you can write your own code

```js
$("a").click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();

//You can write other code what you want to write

});
```

This code may help you to get override the other code
 or you may use e.stopPropagation() in stead of e.preventDefault(); it will stop all other active events

Comment: The problem here is not that `mouseover` event propagating from the child to the parent, but rather the `mouseover` event NOT propagating.